# How to reset automatically the oracle sequence number before it reach to the maximum number

Tags: oracle, sequence

I have a sequence in my oracle database and set the maximum number to 99999. I like to automate resetting to 10000 before it reach to 99999. Below is my script of `myseq`.

```
create sequence myseq
    minvalue 1
    maxvalue 99999
    increment by 1
    start with 10000;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to define sequence as CYCLE:

```
create sequence myseq minvalue 10000 maxvalue 99999 increment by 1 CYCLE;
```

It will start from minvalue again when reaches maxvalue, i.e. generate numbers in cycle.

Oracle spec says:

> **CYCLE** - Specify CYCLE to indicate that the sequence continues to generate values after reaching either its maximum or minimum value.
>   After an ascending sequence reaches its maximum value, it generates
>   its minimum value. After a descending sequence reaches its minimum, it
>   generates its maximum value.

Comment: Thanks Rust . This is definitely what I want .

Answer (score 2):

If you are in 12c, you can use the `IDENTITY` column and get rid off the `SEQUENCE` mechanism.

If you are not on 12c, assuming that your primary key is populated via sequence using a trigger. What you can do is :

Create a trigger with the logic to reset the sequence back to normal,
   i.e. after every time you purge the table, the sequence would START
   WITH 1 and INCREMENT BY 1. using ALTER SEQUENCE.

The sequence logic part using alter statement (Thanks to Tom Kyte for
   this) :

```
create or replace
procedure reset_sequence(p_seq in varchar2)
is
    l_value number;
begin

-- Select the next value of the sequence

    execute immediate
    'select ' || p_seq || 
    '.nextval from dual' INTO l_value;

-- Set a negative increment for the sequence, 
-- with value = the current value of the sequence

    execute immediate
    'alter sequence ' || p_seq || 
    ' increment by -' || l_value || ' minvalue 0';

-- Select once from the sequence, to 
-- take its current value back to 0

    execute immediate
    'select ' || p_seq || 
    '.nextval from dual' INTO l_value;

-- Set the increment back to 1

    execute immediate
    'alter sequence ' || p_seq || 
    ' increment by 1 minvalue 0';
end;
/
```

***Update*** : Don't know what I was thinking initially. Based on the other answer, you need `ALTER SEQUENCE` to `TURN ON CYCLE`.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE sequence_name CYCLE;
```

Comment: I updated my answer, you can use `ALTER SEQUENCE seq_name CYCLE`

Comment: I think that ALTER SEQUENCE seq_name CYCLE is not enough. You need to set minvalue as 10000 instead of start with. otherwise it will start from 1 when reaches maxvalue.